# How to select messages from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have two fields in my mysql table `from_id` and `to_id`

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE (`from_id` = $user1_id AND `to_id` = $user2_id) OR 
      (`from_id` = $user2_id AND `to_id` = $user1_id)
```

but this is kinda weird, is there a way to make a query more royal?

its like I want all the messages that I've send and those who were sent to me

Comment: What is "Royal" query. This query is efficient enough.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya just bad habit thinking that my queries are bad xD and there is someone who knows better

Comment: Use `Explain` statement results to compare the queries, before judging a query is "royal" enough :)

Comment: That `OR` will lead to scanning the entire table, regardless of what indexes you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE `from_id` = $user1_id AND `to_id` = $user2_id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `from_id` = $user2_id AND `to_id` = $user1_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE (`from_id`, `to_id`) IN (($user1_id,$user2_id),($user2_id,$user1_id))
```

Comment: Union all - scares me :D, but this is an interesting approach, thank you

Comment: The `UNION` will be fast if you have both of these: `INDEX(from_id, to_id), INDEX(to_id, from_id)`.  The `IN` will be slow in older versions of MySQL; I don't know whether the Optimizer has gotten smart lately.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for comment. I have no ability to check it now but as a rule of thumb I could guess that MySQL should support [OR expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - MySQL does not have "OR expansion".  Nor anything in parallel.  Only recently does it do anything better than a table scan for `WHERE(a,b) IN ...`.  Only recently MySQL added an optimization to avoid temp table when doing certain cases of `UNION ALL`.  Note how Oracle did not get around to `OR` until version 12.  Well, it may be a decade before MySQL gets there.  _All of these are in the "long tail" of optimizations that benefit <<1% of queries._

Comment: @RickJames Wow, it means that MySQL optimizer is way behind Oracle/SQL Server or PostgreSQL :/